# Tranformación Dataframe - una fila a varias según condiciones

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente problema

Tengo un dataframe que contiene una cantidad de registros determinados, algunos de esos registros tienen una variable que es "Genérica", cuando tengo este tipo de variables, tengo que repartir esos registros proporcionalmente de acuerdo a como se distribuyen estas variables genéricas.

Ejemplo:

Dataframe A(dfA):

```
Nombre Fecha       Número Clasificacion Importe
Fulano 12/07/2021  234    Generico      10.000
```

Dataframe B (DfB)

```
Asignacion Generico
A          0,12
B          0,28
C          0,32
D          0,28
```

Lo que tengo que necesito realizar es crear una fila en el dataframe A para cada uno de los valores del Dataframe B, que en definitiva es como se reparten estos valores genéricos, el dataframe resultante debería ser así:

Dataframe resultante(df):

```
Nombre Fecha       Número Clasificacion Importe
Fulano 12/07/2021  234    A             1.200
Fulano 12/07/2021  234    B             2.800
Fulano 12/07/2021  234    C             3.200
Fulano 12/07/2021  234    D             2.800
```

Lo que he intentado es lo siguiente:

```
for i in range(0,len(DfA)):
    df.loc[i,'Importe'] = dfA.loc[i,'Generico']*DfB.iloc[0,1]
    df.loc[i,'Importe'] = dfA.loc[i,'Generico']*DfB.iloc[1,1]
    df.loc[i,'Importe'] = dfA.loc[i,'Generico']*DfB.iloc[2,1]
    df.loc[i,'Importe'] = dfA.loc[i,'Generico']*DfB.iloc[3,1]
```

Pero encuentro complejo añadir esta función porque estoy realizando una operación manual en la multiplicación que hago con el DfB.

Comment: Y que has intentado?

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario Christian, ahí te compartí lo que he realizado, seguido a esto que he creado debo eliminar ese registro Genérico en DfA y añadir los 4 registros que le sustiuyen creados en el Df final. Es decir, para cada registro genérico en dfA, debo crear 4 registros sustitutos con esas ccondiciones. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es un `cross join` o producto cartesiano. Pandas tiene una forma muy sencilla de resolverlo mediante [`merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html?highlight=cross#pandas-merge):

```
dfA.merge(dfB, how='cross')
```

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfA = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Fulano', '12/07/2021', '234', 'Generico', '10.000'],
                             ['Zutano', '12/07/2021', '234', 'Generico', '10.000']]),
                   columns=['Nombre', 'Fecha', 'Número', 'Clasificacion', 'Importe'])

dfB = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A', '0,12'],
                             ['B', '0,28'],
                             ['C', '0,32'],
                             ['D', '0,28']]),
                             columns = ['Asignacion', 'Generico'])


print(dfA.merge(dfB, how='cross'))

   Nombre       Fecha Número Clasificacion Importe Asignacion Generico
0  Fulano  12/07/2021    234      Generico  10.000          A     0,12
1  Fulano  12/07/2021    234      Generico  10.000          B     0,28
2  Fulano  12/07/2021    234      Generico  10.000          C     0,32
3  Fulano  12/07/2021    234      Generico  10.000          D     0,28
4  Zutano  12/07/2021    234      Generico  10.000          A     0,12
5  Zutano  12/07/2021    234      Generico  10.000          B     0,28
6  Zutano  12/07/2021    234      Generico  10.000          C     0,32
7  Zutano  12/07/2021    234      Generico  10.000          D     0,28
```

Comment: Excelente Patricio!! Muchas gracias por tus aportes.